# Can non-English questions be asked and be answered at the same language in this site?

Tags: discussion

There are many users from different countries that do not know English language.
Why they should be enforced to ask questions in English language in this site?

There are many users who can answer the non-English questions.

For example a user with Pakistan ask a question in Urdu language and another user answer in Urdu.